Running 2 robot files parallelly in chrome using robot framework
I have two robot files lets say a.robot and b.robot.
A.robot files takes around 30 mins to execute and b.robot takes around 1 hour to execute.
I want to run both of them parallelly, so that both of these files are executed in 1 hour.
So far, Whatever I have tried using is not working as Robot Framework will launch 2 or multiple chrome instances but execution is taking place in only one of them rest of the chrome instances are just set at homepage with no automation taking place there.
This is the error I get:
Error while trying to run the robot files together
For execution I'm just providing the folder path where both of these files are present and both a.robot and b.robot are present in same folder.

Have you tried running tests in parallel using Pabot? It is not possible to help without seeing what you have tried so far. If possible edit and add some code in your question.

I ran the below script:
pabot --processes 2 --listener robot-tc-listener --outputdir %PabotResults_DIR% --output output.xml --report report.html --log log.html robot/files/path/
It launches multiple chrome windows but automation takes place in only one chrome window, rest of the chrome windows stay at home page.

Also tried:
pabot --suite oncb --suite oncb_customer src/tests/init_example/
to be more specific, I followed:
https://forum.robotframework.org/t/how-to-structure-a-suite-setup-with-multiple-robot-files/6622/4
And this is the error I got:
Setup failed:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

You probably need to use Create Webdriver keyword and pass portargument for it.  Point being, launching multiple separate webdrivers could colide with their settings unless you ensure each instance gets unique settings ..

eg, its not how you start pabot but how the webdriver is initialized
